# Get the current fragment object

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my `main.xml` I have

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameTitle"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/title_bg">
            <fragment
              android:name="com.fragment.TitleFragment"
              android:id="@+id/fragmentTag"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  </FrameLayout>
```

And I'm setting fragment object like this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment newFragment = new FragmentType1();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameTitle, casinodetailFragment, "fragmentTag");

// fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

It is setting different types of Fragment objects (`FragmentType2,FragmentType3,...`) at different time. Now at some point of time I need to identify which object is currently there.

In **short** I need to do something like this:

```
Fragment currentFragment = //what is the way to get current fragment object in FrameLayout R.id.frameTitle
```

I tried the following

```
TitleFragment titleFragmentById = (TitleFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frameTitle);
```

and

```
    TitleFragment titleFragmentByTag = (TitleFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragmentTag");
```

But **both the objects (titleFragmentById and titleFragmentByTag  ) are `null`**
Did I miss something?
I'm using `Compatibility Package, r3` and developing for `API level 7`.

`findFragmentById()` and `findFragmentByTag()` will work if we have set fragment using `fragmentTransaction.replace` or `fragmentTransaction.add`, but will `return null` if we have set the object at xml (like what I have done in my `main.xml`). I think I'm missing something in my XML files.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21104084/80428

Comment: Does @CommonsWare answer help you, because I still get null?

Answer (score 269, accepted):

> Now at some point of time I need to identify which object is currently there

Call `findFragmentById()` on `FragmentManager` and determine which fragment is in your `R.id.frameTitle` container.

If you are using the `androidx` edition of `Fragment` — as you should in modern apps — , use `getSupportFragmentManager()` on your `FragmentActivity`/`AppCompatActivity` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It will work if we have set fragment using `fragmentTransaction.replac`e or `fragmentTransaction.add` but will not get if we have set it at xml. See my edit 2

Comment: @Labeeb P: You cannot modify fragments declared in the layout resources.

Comment: Creating a class to hold the currently visible tab/ fragment will work also, I jjust tried that. Hope there are no failures.

Comment: @CommonsWare `findFragmentByTag` returning null in case of `ActionBar` Tabs. In my `Activity` which is extending `ActionBarActivity` i'm first adding tabs to `ActionBar` and then finding it!

Comment: @CommonsWare  inside my `onTabSelected` i have also tried `executePendingTransactions()` by still no luck. Could you please help!

Comment: @CommonsWare This worked when i tried to find fragment from `onResume()`. Is it possible to do this from `onCreate()`?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: You can try `executePendingTransactions()` on `FragmentManager` after calling `commit()` on the transaction, though I have not tried this. Or you can use `setContentView()` to use a layout file with a `<fragment>` tag. Either of those happen synchronously, and so the fragment will exist within the `onCreate()` call itself where you used `executePendingTransaction()` or `setContentView()`. Otherwise, an ordinary `FragmentTransaction` is processed asynchronously, and it will not have even begun by the time `onCreate()` ends.

Comment: @CommonsWare I knew this would have worked in normal scenario. but i'm using ActionBarTabs and inside `onTabselected()` of `TabListener` fragment is being **just** added we can't call commit because system calls it for us else it results in *exception*.

Comment: Though i did handle the scenario by moving the call to `onResume()` and used a `boolean` flag to handle but still curious to know the work around other way. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I just went through a bunch of this - seems a major confusion happens because findFragmentByTag() does not use the Tag presented by the BackStackEntry ( sort of an assumption)  The two tags are specified independently - the findFragmentByTag() uses the getTag() on the fragment if you want to use the tag in the entry to find the fragment you have to separately specify it. It will not default to the tag of the fragment referenced by the entry if left as null.

Comment: When I call this I still get null

Comment: How to determine if a fragment is still in backstack?

Comment: @eCDroid: I do not think that there is a direct way to do that, sorry. You can ask the `FragmentManager` about back stack entries, but the details that you get back do not include the `Fragment` itself. If you do a good job with the names and IDs, you might be able to determine the fragment for a `BackStackEntry` by those pieces of data, though.

Comment: Using tags (For fragments) and name (for backstack state) i still didn't find any api that can tell if a fragment is in the back stack. The only viable solution that worked is to do like this `Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(name);

        return fragment != null;`

Comment: @eCDroid: `getBackStackEntryCount()` and `getBackStackEntry()` on `FragmentManager` will tell you what is on that manager's back stack. `findFragmentByTag()` has nothing to do with the back stack, though depending on your use of fragments it might work for your specific scenario.

Comment: Official doc of `findFragmentByTag` is `Finds a fragment that was identified by the given tag either when inflated from XML or as supplied when added in a transaction. This first searches through fragments that are currently added to the manager's activity; if no such fragment is found, then all fragments currently on the back stack are searched.` note this **if no such fragment is found, then all fragments currently on the back stack are searched**

Comment: While getBackStackEntry() worked with index not id or tag. So i have to iterate the whole fragment manager and do is instanceOf with class name. Which one you suggest.

Comment: @eCDroid: My point is that `findFragmentByTag()` does not indicate if the fragment is on the back stack. It simply indicates if the fragment is known by the manager, which includes fragments not on the back stack. Your point regarding `instanceof` does not make sense to me, as there is nothing in the `BackStackEntry` that contains your `Fragment`. My suggestion is that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151393/discussion-between-ec-droid-and-commonsware).

Comment: Okay finally this `public boolean isBackStackExists(String tag)
    {
        FragmentManager manager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();

        for(int i = 0; i < manager.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++)
        {
            String backStackTag = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName();

            if(backStackTag.equals(tag))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }` works for me. I have to use same tag for fragment and backstack.

Answer (score 116):

Try this,

```
Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

this will give u the current fragment, then you may compare it to the fragment class and do your stuffs.

```
    if (currentFragment instanceof NameOfYourFragmentClass) {
     Log.v(TAG, "find the current fragment");
  }
```

Comment: Where to put this line ?

Comment: Sometimes you have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead, and will get null without the `support` part

Comment: Remove the quotes from around "NAME OF YOUR FRAGMENT CLASS".

Answer (score 38):

I think you can use **onAttachFragment** event may be useful to catch which fragment is active.

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(fragment.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: i can able to get which fragment i am attached. My dought is when i change the orientation then i need to display the same view not another view so how to do this.

Comment: This doesn't work because it doesn't update the active fragment when you go back.

Comment: @Justin so we just need to use onDetach also with a weakreference list

Answer (score 13):

I think you should do:

```
Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragmentTag");
```

The reason is because you set the tag "fragmentTag" to the last fragment you have added (when you called replace).

Comment: Thanks I have corrected it. Its a typo mistake while writing this question. It will work if we have set fragment using `fragmentTransaction.replac`e or `fragmentTransaction.add` but will not get if we have set it at xml. See my edit 2

Comment: doesn't this solution means that you have to put same tag for multiple fragments? otherwise how would you know `fragmentTag` is the tag for the current fragment?

Answer (score 12):

You can get the list of the fragments and look to the last one.

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();
    Fragment lastFragment = fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1);
```

But sometimes (when you navigate back) list size remains same but some of the last elements are null. So in the list I iterated to the last not null fragment and used it.

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm != null) {
        List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();
        if (fragments != null) {
            for(int i = fragments.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                Fragment fragment = fragments.get(i);
                if(fragment != null) {
                    // found the current fragment

                    // if you want to check for specific fragment class
                    if(fragment instanceof YourFragmentClass) {
                        // do something
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use the `getFragments()` method. It is marked with `@hide` and was not supposed to be included with the support library jar. It should not be considered as a part of the exported API.

Comment: Heh, then they should have created a method that lets you do exactly what `getFragments()` does, because you need it quite often. I think it's actually publicly available now, too.

Answer (score 10):

This is the simplest solution and work for me.

1.) you add your fragment

```
ft.replace(R.id.container_layout, fragment_name, "fragment_tag").commit();
```

2.)

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container_layout);

if(currentFragment.getTag().equals("fragment_tag"))

{

 //Do something

}

else

{

//Do something

}
```

Answer (score 9):

It might be late but I hope it helps someone else, also @CommonsWare has posted the correct answer.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment_byID = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
//OR
Fragment fragment_byTag = fm.findFragmentByTag("fragment_tag");
```

Comment: This doesn't allow you to get the active fragment, since you don't necessarily know the id or tag.

Answer (score 7):

You can create field in your parent Activity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Fragment fr;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

And then inside each fragment class:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fr = this;
}
```

Your 'fr' field is current fragment Object

It's working also with popBackStack()

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the simplest way is:

```
public MyFragment getVisibleFragment(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
        if(fragment != null && fragment.getUserVisibleHint())
            return (MyFragment)fragment;
    }
    return null;
}
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a while, but I'll this here in case it helps someone out.

The **right answer** by far is (and the selected one) the one from CommonsWare. I was having the same problem as posted, the following

```
MyFragmentClass fragmentList = 
            (MyFragmentClass) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragementID);
```

kept on returning null. My mistake was really silly, in my xml file:

```
<fragment
    android:tag="@+id/fragementID"
    android:name="com.sf.lidgit_android.content.MyFragmentClass"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

The mistake was that I had **android:tag** INSTEAD OF **android:id**.

Answer (score 3):

1. Do a check (which fragment in the activity container) in the onStart method;

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   Fragment fragmentCurrent = getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.constraintLayout___activity_main___container);
   }
   ```
2. Some check:

   ```
   if (fragmentCurrent instanceof MenuFragment)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

@Hammer response worked for me, im using to control a floating action button

```
final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            android.app.Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
            Log.d("VIE",String.valueOf(currentFragment));
            if (currentFragment instanceof PerfilFragment) {
                PerfilEdit(view, fab);
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are extending from AbstractActivity, you could use the getFragments() method:

```
for (Fragment f : getFragments()) {
    if (f instanceof YourClass) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining the fragment in the activity's XML layour then in the `Activity` make sure you call `setContentView()` before calling `findFragmentById()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the BackStack...and ONLY if you are using the back stack, then try this:

```
rivate Fragment returnToPreviousFragment() {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Fragment topFrag = null;

    int idx = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (idx > 1) {
        BackStackEntry entry = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(idx - 2);
        topFrag = fm.findFragmentByTag(entry.getName());
    }

    fm.popBackStack();

    return topFrag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the current fragment class name -->

```
String fr_name = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container).getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked on an activity involving multiple fragments so thought to share the method I used here:

Firstly, I declared a function getCurrentFragment() which returned me, yeah you guessed it, the current fragment, lol.

```
private fun getCurrentFragment(): Fragment? {
    return supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
}
```

Then I override the onBackPressed function in the activity to define the navigation within fragments. Suppose, I wanted to show fragment 2 if user is in fragment 3 and presses back so I did something like this to achieve this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (getCurrentFragment() is Fragment3) {
            showFragment2()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

And in showFragment2() I did something like this:

```
private fun showFragment2() {
        val fragment = Fragment2.newInstance()
        supportFragmentManager.commit {
            replace(R.id.FragmentContainerView, fragment, "Add a tag here")
        }
    }
```

I think this should give better idea to people looking on how to navigate through fragments within an activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can check which fragment is currently loaded by this

```
        supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
        val myFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments.last()

        if (null != myFragment && myFragment is HomeFragment) {
            //HomeFragment is visible or currently loaded
        } else {
            //your code
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function in Kotlin:

```kotlin
supportFragmentManager.fragments.run {
    getOrNull(size - 1)?.let { currentFragment ->
        ...
    }
}
```