# how to identify the current fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

My question is not easy to describe, but I will do my best:

On my tablet-app I have one activity with a `listFragment` A on left side and a `detailFragment` B on right side. So when I click an item on the list, the `detailFragment` shows the proper details of the chosen (list) item.

Now when I click a button on my `detailFragment` B. the fragment gets swapped with a new `Fragment` from type infoFragment. The `listFragment`   on left side stays as it is.

So now, when I click another item on the List, I want the `infoFragment` to vanish and get a `detailFragment` once again.

My problem is, that i need some kind of check if currently there is an `infoFragment` or a `detailFragment` displayed. So that I can either just refresh the `detailFragment` OR stop the `infoFragment` and build a new `detailFragment`.

idea:

```
 if ( //detailFragment is active ) {
        updateContent();
 }
 else {
        FragmentManager.buildDetailFragment();
 }
```

have been fiddling for hours now, any help is appreciated!!

**How can i figure it out whether there is a detailFragment or listFragment displayed?**

**edit:**
i change my detailFragment with the infoFragment here:

```
FragmentManager fm  = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.details_fragment);

fragment = new InfoFragment();
fm.beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.details_fragment, fragment)
  .commit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a `Fragment` to your fragment manager with a [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) you can specify a key value. You can then [findFragmentByTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29) which will determine if the `Fragment` with that key value has been added to the fragment manager.

So long as you are not using a `ViewPager` or some other structure where multple fragments are added at once, searching for whether your fragment manager contains a fragment by tag will let you know which is currently displayed. You can then use the results of that search to update the fragment since the result is a reference to the fragment itself.

This means you can pass data from the `FragmentActivity` to the fragment directly by calling any publicly accessable fragment methods. For example

```
Fragment displayedFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG);
if(displayedFragment != null){ //null if no fragment with tag value       
    displayedFragment.updateList() //public method within fragment
}
```

Comment: intresting aspect. i will look into it now

Comment: findFragmentByTag really did the trick. This is very useful, Lesson learned !!

Answer (score 2):

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENT");
if (myFragment.isVisible()) {
  // add your code here
}
```

From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9295085/932011)

Answer (score 2):

```
FragmentManager fm  = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_id);
```

now we can get the fragment name by getClass

```
fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get class of fragment and check which one it exactly is by calling `getClass()`.

Comment: the output is in both cases the detailFragment. think that it won't get me the solution :/