# Update fragment from Activity from different thread

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm very new to Androind, trying to figure how fragment and activity should be work together. I have a very ugly layout. 1 activity and 1 "root" fragment. When user click on left menu fragment are replaced by fragment manager.

```
expandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {

        LeftMenuItem group = groups.get(i);
        String fragmentTag = group.getFragmentTag();
        if (fragmentTag.equals(Fragment1.TAG)) {
            Fragment1 fragment = (Fragment1) currentFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(Fragment1.TAG);
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = new Fragment1();
            }
            FragmentTransaction ft = currentFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.root_frame, fragment, Fragment1.TAG);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

        } else if (fragmentTag.equals(Fragment2.TAG)) {
```

I assume code above is supposed to replace current fragment with new one. Fragments are always null actually. I do not know why.

In onCreateView of RootFragment Fragment1 is created by default.

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "savedInstanceState is null, creating Framgent1");

        Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
        FragmentTransaction ft = currentFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.root_frame, fragment, Fragment1.TAG);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

In `onCreateView` of rootFragment, rootFragment replaces itself with another Fragment1, which looks very ugly for me. Is it well known Androind pattern or just bad design ?

Let's assume that'm sending httpRequest from onCreateView of MyActivity using Volley. Once I received response I need to update Fragment1 UI from callback. How can I do it ?

1. Should I try to find fragment using findFragmentByTag in my activity and update UI directly ? Is http volley response is in the same thread ? If no, it is ok to update UI from different thread ?
2. Should I use a Handler class to send message from Activity to Fragment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Should I try to find fragment using findFragmentByTag in my activity and update UI directly ? Is http volley response is in the same thread ? If no, it is ok to update UI from different thread ?

> findFragmentByTag will not be useful since as soon as replace is
>   called, the previous fragment is destroyed. If you have only few
>   fragment you want to switch, you can use hte below solution :
>
> [How can I switch between two fragments, without recreating the fragments each time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713128/how-can-i-switch-between-two-fragments-without-recreating-the-fragments-each-ti)

Answer to second part of your question 1 :

> Volley response is always called on the main thread to its perfectly
>   ok to update UI on the callback. You should never update UI elements
>   on any thread other than MAIN / UI thread.

2. Should I use a Handler class to send message from Activity to Fragment ?

> You can choose to send the message by handler but if usually android documentation suggests to send communicate between activity and attached fragments via callbacks
>
> https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html