# Keyboard navigation: how to move other fragment?

Tags: android, uinavigationcontroller, keyboard

I am searching how to move the focus from one fragment to another fragment.

I am watching to below page to implement the keyboard navigation.
[keyboard navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation)

Our app is only provided to landscape table.
So it has 2 fragments. (Left side, right side)
And what I want to do is when I input "->" right arrow keyboard on left side fragment, how can I change the focus to the right side fragment?
And it should be able to come back from contents fragment to menu fragment.

Is it possible? then Can I know a hint, please?

[image]

---

I am adding more details about this question.

This question is about focus navigation using the HW keyboard.

I already write the guide document link (https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation)

Using below attributes, I can move the focus.
 - android:nextFocusUp
 - android:nextFocusDown
 - android:nextFocusLeft
 - android:nextFocusRight

But our app is consist of 2 fragments.
In the left menu fragment, I can move the focus using the arrow keyboard.
And when I input "right arrow" or "enter" keyboard or anything, I want to move the focus to the right side contents fragment.
And when I input the arrow keyboard, (up, down, left, right) the focus is moved in the right side fragment not left side.

But if I want to come back from the right side to left side, I want to do that.

For example, I moved the focus to the final view, and I input "right or down arrow", I should come back to the left side fragment.

Following the guide document (https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation), this is defined on the xml file.

It means I can move the focus only in the xml file.

What I want to do is change the focus beyond the xml file.

Comment: So you want to switch between fragments and keep the data while switching them in short?

Comment: My question is about the "Keyboard Navigation". In one activity view, there are no issue. But in case of 2 fragments, I want to use the "Keyboard Navigation" like one activity.

Comment: Your description of problem is confusing and what you want is unclear. So when You press arrow on keyboard what exactly do you want

Comment: If you want to communicate with two of this fragment then you can use interface for that. Once user click on "->" Right arrow call the interface method and other fragment should implements that interface.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22714222/10290109

Comment: I apologize for any unclear questions. So I added more details.

Comment: I also have this problem, so how did you solve this problem?