# How to switch between fragments without recreating fragments each time?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

While switching between fragments using bottomNavigationView the fragments are recreated every time when button is pressed.

Here is my code:

```
private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    //switching fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentguest, fragment)
                .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
     Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.eventsguest:
            fragment = new Events();
            break;
        case R.id.about_usguest:
            fragment = new About_Us();
            break;
    }

    return loadFragment(fragment);
}
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/76120054/14773942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replace method destroys your fragments. One workaround is to set them to Visibility.GONE, another (less easy) method is to hold them in a variable. If you do that, make sure you don't leak memory left and right.

this question answered by [meredrica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633375/meredrica) in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713128/how-can-i-switch-between-two-fragments-without-recreating-the-fragments-each-ti)

Answer (score 0):

Do not create fragment every time (`fragment = new Events();`) You can keep the reference of both the fragments in object fields and return the already created fragment in your `onNavigationItemSelected` method.
Or you can combine `ViewPager` with the `BottomNavigationView`. Refer this [article](https://droidmentor.com/bottomnavigationview-with-viewpager-android/) and if you do not know much about ViewPager. Refer [this](https://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial).