# Using onSaveInstanceState in BottomNavigationView's fragment replacing

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, onsaveinstancestate

I am trying to use onSaveInstanceState method to minimize the server capacity in my app. I am trying to avoid accessing the server everytime the user changes his/her bottom navigation view(now inferred to bnv).
(I only could find the examples of onSaveInstanceState when its rotating the phone)
I followed every fragment's lifecycle methods but onSaveInstanceState would not be called. I also figured out that when I replace the fragment in BottomNavigationView, let's say, fragmentA to fragmentB, fragmentA reaches onDestroyView when it is replaced. So why won't onSaveInstanceState be called??

I am stuck with this problem for days.. Could anyone give some advice?

My MainActivity codes.

```
public static final String TAG = "LifeCycles";

FragmentManager manager;
FragmentA fragmentA;
FragmentB fragmentB;
FragmentC fragmentC;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.navigation_home:
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.testFrame, fragmentA).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.testFrame, fragmentB).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.testFrame, fragmentC).commit();
                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.w(TAG, "----- Activity: onCreate ------");
    manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    fragmentA = new FragmentA();
    fragmentB = new FragmentB();
    fragmentC = new FragmentC();

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.testFrame, fragmentA).commit();

    findViewById(R.id.toActivity).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SemiActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `replace` destroys the fragment, it doesn't save the instance because it considers that fragment as "discarded" so at no point it will be restored. Similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713128/how-can-i-switch-between-two-fragments-without-recreating-the-fragments-each-ti

Comment: so are you suggesting  to keep the fragment with hide, add, and show?
And not by trying to recall data by onSavedInstanceState()?

Comment: and refresh the activity when data changes?