# Controlling Back Button in a non Activity class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, back-button

I have an Actionbar app with fragments and a `TabFragment extends Fragment` class, where I customize the functionality of my fragments.

I want to be able to control what the back button does.

```
@Overriding onBackPressed()
```

won't work because I am not in an Activity,
nor will

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
       //my code here
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

My goal is to hide some specific Views when I press back based on true/false value of a boolean variable. Any suggestions on how I might be able to manipulate this functionality? Thanks!

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: In the onBackPress of the Activity check to see which Fragment is Visible and accordingly perform what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/get-currently-displayed-fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, but I realized that you had to deal with the back button in the activity where you are running your fragments from. You need to override the `onBackPressed()` in the activity code, not inside the fragment code. Then you can check to see which fragment is visible and do what you want accordingly.
This code is in my activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    try
    {
        final LiveWorkFragment liveFragment = (LiveWorkFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("live_work");//LiveWorkFragment is a fragment
        final NonLiveWorkFragment nonLiveFragment = (NonLiveWorkFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("non_live");//NonLiveWorkFragment is a fragment
        final SignatureFragment signatureFragment = (SignatureFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("signature");//this is a Fragment too

        if(liveFragment == null && nonLiveFragment == null && signatureFragment == null)
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        if(liveFragment != null)
        {
            if (liveFragment.isVisible())
            {
                //do what you want
            }
        }
    }
}
```