# Update selected state of navigation drawer after back press

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

Whats the proper way to handle the selected state of the navigation drawer after back press?

I have a navigation drawer with n entries (in a listview) like the SDK sample in Android Studio.
When i click on the navigation drawer entries i want them to be added to the back stack, so i can move back to them.

In onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int pos) i have

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (position == 0) {
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, new FragmentA());
        } else if (position == 1) {
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, new FragmentB());
        } else {
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, new FragmentC());
        }
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

When i click on the second entry in the drawer, B gets selected and replaces A. If i click the back button afterwards, Fragment A is shown again like it should, but B is still selected in the navigation drawer.

How can i get the selection status of the drawer updated after pressing back?

Somehow i need a call to  mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true); or NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem(int position). But to which position? How do i remeber it?

Intercept with onBackPressed?

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {}
```

But how do i know which fragment is active again? And to which position it corresponds.

Is there some easy solution i am blind to see? It seems that using back in combination with the navigation drawer and updating the selection status is a standard pattern.

Answer (score 8):

This pattern is described in the [Implement Back Navigation for Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments) section of the "Proper Back Navigation" documentation.

> If your application updates other user interface elements to reflect
>   the current state of your fragments, such as the action bar, remember
>   to update the UI when you commit the transaction. You should update
>   your user interface after the back stack changes in addition to when
>   you commit the transaction. **You can listen for when a
>   `FragmentTransaction` is reverted by setting up a
>   `FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener`**:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
    new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            // Update your UI here.
        }
    });
```

That would be the proper place to refresh the current option in the navigation drawer.

Comment: This answers only the question when to update. I could also use onBackPressed(). The main question is which position should be highlighted in the drawer? I probably need to get the old, now "active" fragment and a mapping fragment->position reverse of that in onNavigationDrawerItemSelected. Maybe store the position as request code with setTargetFragment?

Comment: @spatialist Yes, that would work, and then notify the drawer in the Fragment's `onCreateView()`. Nevertheless, I would still suggest using a listener instead of `onBackPressed()`. For example, pressing Back may not actually change the current fragment (e.g. dismissing a search view).

Answer (score 7):

today I had the same strugle. I solved it by implementing an Interface `FragmentToActivity` in **every** Fragment and in my one and only MainActivity.

**Interface:**

```
public interface FragmentToActivity {
    public void SetNavState(int id);
}
```

**Fragments:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((FragmentToActivity) getActivity()).SetNavState(R.id.nav_myitemid); //just add this line
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
public void SetNavState(int id) {
    NavigationView nav = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    nav.setCheckedItem(id);
}
```

And if you have no idea, where `R.id.nav_myitemid` comes from, here is my *activity_main_drawer.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_myitemid"
            android:title="@string/home" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Great! but i have one question, why you used interface function instead of a normal public function?

Comment: @KhanStan99 He need callback,`setCheckedItem` only can be done from parent activity instead of Fragment,

Comment: Good and clean!

Answer (score 5):

I have had alot of trouble trying to figure out a solution to this problem and the solution I ended up using isn't "nice" in my opinion, but it works.

In my application i ended up adding a fragments position in the navigation drawer, when i added the fragment to the backstack. This way i could call setItemChecked with the position in my onBackStackChanged(). So basicly what i did was this:

```
@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    String name = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()-1).getName();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(Integer.parseInt(name),true);
}

public class DrawerItemClickListener implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment;

    switch (position) {
        case 0: // Home
            fragment = new ContentFragment();
            break;
        case 1: // Another
           fragment = new AnotherFragment();
            break;
        default: // Logout
        {
            finish();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            return;
        }
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(Integer.toString(position))
            .commit();

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mNavigationItems[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Comment: Wow this is brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot :) had to spend enough time with ugly way until found your answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Building upon @matiash 's excellent answer (be sure to +1 his/hers if you +1 my answer)

To start, we're assuming we're in the `Activity`

```
getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
    new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            // Update your UI here.
        }
    });
```

You can find the current fragment with the following:

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24589081/878159)

```
Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_container);
if (f instanceof CustomFragmentClass) {
    // do something with f
    f.doSomething();
}
```

That should get you a step closer.  Then something like this will get you a reference to your nav drawer:

```
nav = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav);
```

Then depending how you setup your drawer fragment code:

```
nav.updateSelected(position);
```

The `updateSelected(int)` method would be in your `NavigationDrawerFragment` class and might look something like this:

```
public void updateSelected(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
}
```

NOTE: there are many ways to do this, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually simple. You already have your navigation view in `Drawer` layout. For each item pressed, it opens the respective fragment, right?
Now go the `onCreateView` of each fragment and do this...

```
NavigationView navigationView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.this_fragment's_item);
```

Also, In your Main Activity where you're handling item click, use an if statement such that

```
if (navigation_view.getMenu().findItem(R.id.account_nav).isChecked())   
  drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

The above avoids creating multiple instances of a fragment on top of itself.

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

This is late but for those who are using navigation menu instead of list, here is how i did it

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
       int position=0;
       Fragment fragment;
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            fragment=new HomeFragment();
            position=0;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {

           fragment=new ProfileFragment();
            position=1;
        }  else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
             fragment=new SettingsFragment();
            position=2;
        }

          getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.relative_container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(""+position)
            .commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

and add listner for backstack

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {

             FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
             String name = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()-1).getName();
               if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
             selectNavigationDrawerItem(Integer.parseInt(name));

        }
    });
```

selectNavigationDrawerItem  method

```
 private void selectNavigationDrawerItem(int position){

               if(position==0){
                   navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
               }
               else if(position==1){
                   navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_profile);
               }
               else if(position==2){
                   navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_settings);   
              }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in kotlin.

In the fragment that you want to be selected and highlighted by the drawer, you simply do:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val navView: NavigationView = activity!!.findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    navView.setCheckedItem(R.id.name_of_this_fragment)

    ...
}
```