# Fragment is shown multiple times

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to show a `Fragment` when a marker is clicked.I'm using `AsyncTask` to show the `Fragment` I tried by setting a bit to avoid multiple times if same marker is tapped within fraction of milliseconds.But it is not working.

```
if (markerclicked == 0)
new AsyncDataLoading().execute();
```

Setting the bit in `onPreExecute()`,

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            markerclicked = 1;

        }
```

showing the Fragment in doInBackground(),

```
dialog_fragment.show(fm, "DetailScreen");
```

and on the `postExecute()`,

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            markerclicked = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Did you use OSM or Google Map maker?

Comment: @Jas use  OnLocation Change to display multiple markers on map or markers click event also

Comment: My issue is not marker. I just want to avoid same fragment being shown twice if the marker is being clicked twice within fraction of seconds

Answer (score 0):

DialogFragment has method isVisible(), if you really want to check that.

Hope this help!

Comment: This is not what i need. I just want to check whether the fragment is already shown or not when the marker is clicked again within a fraction of millisecond.