# Webview does not reload

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, android-studio

I am using fragments and have added a item on the action bar to refresh webview named **airport_menuRefresh** but when ever i click it nothing happens. I have 3 tabs. I have tried different methods but neither of them works.
Here is the code of my 1tab(tab1 only contains the not working logic to refresh).

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;    
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

private ProgressBar progress;
private WebView myWebView;



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String url = "http://google.com";
    int delay = 6 * 1000;
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);
    myWebView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewGames);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new myWebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    progress = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progress.setMax(100);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable(url, myWebView);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, String url) {
            GamesFragment.this.progress.setProgress(0);
            View.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }



    });



    myWebView.setOnKeyListener(new android.view.View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
         public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            WebView webView = (WebView) v;

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
        }
    });



   return rootView;

}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.airport_menuRefresh:
            GamesFragment.this.myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

     String url;
    private WebView mywebview;

    public MyRunnable(String url, WebView wv) {
        this.url = url;

        this.mywebview = wv;
    }

    public void run() {

        mywebview.loadUrl(url);

    }
}



private class myWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        GamesFragment.this.setValue(newProgress);
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
}




public void setValue(int progress) {
    this.progress.setProgress(progress);
}


}
```

Here is my main Activity:

```
 import android.annotation.TargetApi;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuInflater;
 import android.view.MenuItem;

 import com.tech.example.adaptor.SlidingTabLayout;
 import com.tech.example.adaptor.TabsPagerAdapter;

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 SlidingTabLayout tabs;
 ViewPager viewPager;
 TabsPagerAdapter adapter;
 Toolbar toolbar;
 private Menu optionsMenu;

CharSequence Titles[]={ "tab1", "tab2", "tab3" };
int Numboftabs =3;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);
    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    setRefreshActionButtonState(true);
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }

        @Override
        public int getDividerColor(int i) {
            return 0;
        }
    });

    tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    this.optionsMenu = menu;
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void setRefreshActionButtonState(final boolean refreshing) {
    if (optionsMenu != null) {
        final MenuItem refreshItem = optionsMenu
                .findItem(R.id.airport_menuRefresh);
        if (refreshItem != null) {
            if (refreshing) {
                refreshItem.setActionView(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
            } else {
                refreshItem.setActionView(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**EDIT**

I edited my main activity like this:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.airport_menuRefresh:

            GamesFragment.myWebView1.loadUrl("http://example.com");

            MoviesFragment.myWebView.loadUrl("http://example2.com");

            TopRatedFragment.myWebView2.loadUrl("http://example3.com");
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Now its reloading but suppose i click reload on tab1 all 3 tabs reloads! Any solution?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Non while compiling.

Comment: You can do one thing to prevent that you can check which fragment you are currently in and base on that you can reload your webview. Do you have 3 fragments there?

Comment: Yes can you give one example please

Comment: You can go to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/get-currently-displayed-fragment

Comment: Any other way to do that?

Comment: What is the reason for when I put onitemselect in main activity then it works but when I put it in any of the 3 fragments it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally i found a solution.**

Moved onCreateOptionsMenu  and onOptionsItemSelected from main activity to fragment tabs like this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   .............
  .............
 .............
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
.................
.................
 }


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
        Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.airport_menuRefresh:

              TopRatedFragment.this.myWebView2.loadUrl("http://myexample.com");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I guess error is in the name of the `WebView` of your methods. As long as you imported:

```
import android.view.View;
```

When in this methow

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, String url) {
//                                              ^-----> UPPERCASE
```

you make this call:

```
View.loadUrl(url);
```

you're trying to call static method of View and not the instance of View from method signature.

try this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
//                                              ^---> lowercase
    GamesFragment.this.progress.setProgress(0);
    view.loadUrl(url);
//  ^---> lowercase
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Still the same nothing happens!

Comment: That cannot be the reason because by your suggestion `View`  don't have `loadUrl()` method.

Comment: And in this case `View.loadUrl()` means its the instace of `WebView`

Comment: @Jordi Castilla see now