# How to get the current visible fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have MainActivity and inside this activity i have four `fragments`. The fragment name are `A,B,C,D.`

```
Fragment currentVisibleFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(null);
```

using this above line i am trying to get the current visible `fragment` but i cant get the current visible fragment.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9295085/2783386

Comment: have you set the fragment tag ?

Answer (score 18):

```
private Fragment getVisibleFragment() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
                return fragment;
        }
        return null;
}
```

**Usage**

```
if (getVisibleFragment() instanceof HomeScreen) {
  // Logic here...
}
```

Were `MainActivity` is the holder and `HomeScreen` is your one of the fragment.

Answer (score 13):

```
Fragment getCurrentFragment()
{
    Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    return currentFragment;
}
```

calling function like this

```
Fragment visibleFragment=getCurrentFragment();
```

calling this function you can get current visible fragment.if Any confusion then feel for free to ask thankx :)

Comment: R.id.content_frame  is view which added fragment in to activity ?

Answer (score 1):

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment getCurrentFragment()
{
    Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout);
    return currentFragment;
}
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should always explain what the code does and how it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkFragmentAvailableOrNot1(String fragmentName) 
{
   Fragment fragment=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);
    if (fragment instanceof FragMercado && fragment.isVisible()) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```