# How to Hide view of a button in Adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-cardview

**I need to use same listview & its item for TWO different Fragment with some modification.**

Here (Screenshot),   (Need to use in Different Fragment)

- I need to **show** the ADD TO WISHLIST & REMOVE in my **1st Layout & 1st Fragment**
- I need to **hide** the ADD TO WISHLIST & REMOVE in my **2nd Layout & 2nd Fragment**

**I need to use Same Adapter.**

How to do this?

[image]

**UPDATE**

**cart_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardlist_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/curved_shape"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/image_4" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cartProduct"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Fusce veh"
                        android:textColor="#9F9F9F" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cartQuantity"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="100 g"
                        android:textColor="#9F9F9F" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="225dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/symbol"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:text="Rs "
                            android:textColor="#9F9F9F" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cartPrice"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.45"
                            android:text="19.99"
                            android:textColor="#9F9F9F" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cartPriceDum"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.45"
                            android:text="19.99"
                            android:textColor="#9F9F9F"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivDecrease"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.1"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_expand" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cartCount"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivIncrease"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.1"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_collapse" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#E4E4E4" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#F8F8F8"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addTowish"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:background="#F8F8F8"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:text="ADD TO WISHLIST"
                    android:textColor="#787878" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#E4E4E4" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/remove"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:background="#F8F8F8"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:text="REMOVE"
                    android:textColor="#787878" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you will have to take position of array in your adapter and according to that set visibility in view holder.

Comment: Need to use this layout from different fragment.So I need to know that the adapter class is called from which fragment( 1st or 2nd ) . Is it possible to know?

Comment: Posted list_item code @RaviVGHL

Comment: @ParamaSudha you have to post java code also :)

Comment: @ParamaSudha i think you need to work as like expandeble listview

Comment: Thank you so much.Got the expected thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104962/discussion-between-ravi-vaghela-and-parama-sudha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use condition based on that you have to use in your adapter :

```
holder.textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

holder.textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

check :

When you add the fragment in your transaction you should use a tag.

```
fragTrans.replace(android.R.id.content, myFragment, "MY_FRAGMENT");
```

later if you want to check if the fragment is visible:

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENT");
if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
   // add your code here
}
```

**Once you get current fragment, you can get that from which fragment adapter class is called.**

Comment: Need to use this layout with different fragment.So I need to know that the adapter class is called from which fragment( 1st or 2nd ) . Is it possible to know?

Comment: check this to get fragment called http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/get-currently-displayed-fragment

Comment: now when you get fragment name you can get adapter class

Comment: Solved it.Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Add constructor to Custom adapter class which takes fragment name as string so that you can check adapter class is called from which fragment

Add Constructor in adapter as :

```
String fragmentName;

public CustomAdapter(String fragmentName) {
    super();
    this.fragmentName = fragmentName;
}
```

Then use it in getView() method as :

```
    if(fragmentName.equals("Fragment1"))
    {
        addTowish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        addTowish.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
put you cart items in different arraylist and show that arraylist in your cart. Then when click on Remove then remove that item from arralist and call notifyDataSetChanged(). on adapter.
Hope It helps. Thanks