# How to detect when back button pressed in fragment android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button

I have project with navigation drawer with fragment, with 5 menu, the problem is when i go to menu 4 and the i press the back button the app closed, but i need the app back to first menu which is all the menu in fragment.

This is code for Main Activity (Navigation Drawer)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
NavigationView mNavigationView;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    /**
     *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
     */

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;

    /**
     * Lets inflate the very first fragment
     * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
     */

    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new Recommendation()).commit();
    /**
     * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
     */

    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();



            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_lux_level_recomen) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new Recommendation()).commit();

            }

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_room_index_calc) {
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new RoomIndex()).commit();
            }

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_utilization_factor_calc) {
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new UtilizationFactorCalculator()).commit();
            }

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_conversions) {
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new Conversion()).commit();
            }
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_lux) {
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new LuxSensor()).commit();
            }


            return false;
        }

    });

    /**
     * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
     */

    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();




}
```

This one of the Menu (Fragment)

```
public class LuxSensor extends Fragment {
TextView textLIGHT_available, textLIGHT_reading;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.lux_sensor,null);
    textLIGHT_reading
            = (TextView)x.findViewById(R.id.LIGHT_reading);

    SensorManager mySensorManager = (SensorManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    Sensor LightSensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    if(LightSensor != null){
        mySensorManager.registerListener(
                LightSensorListener,
                LightSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }else{
        textLIGHT_available.setText("Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT NOT Available");
    }
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    return x;
}





private final SensorEventListener LightSensorListener
        = new SensorEventListener(){

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT){
            textLIGHT_reading.setText(event.values[0]+" LUX");
        }
    }

};
```

}

I have tried solution in internet but it still closed

Comment: make an function in fragment and call it from onBackpressed() from activity using fragment object.

Comment: my answer should be the accepted one. it provides the perfect solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new Recommendation()).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In **fragment** you should use something like this:

```
  @Override
    //Pressed return button - returns to the results menu
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

                 //your code

                   return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: When the keyboard is open, I have to click twice to execute my code.

Answer (score 12):

onCreateView of fragment add this

Java

```java
requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(activity, new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    @Override
    public void handleOnBackPressed() {
        // in here you can do logic when backPress is clicked
    }
});
```

Kotlin

```kotlin
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        // in here you can do logic when backPress is clicked
    }
})
```

Comment: this code goes in loop

Comment: Yes this method is clearly the best way since onBackPressed is deprecated. But this callback handle the event. What if I just want to be aware of the event and not handle it ?

Answer (score 6):

In main activity you need to override the following function

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here to check what fragment you are on and handle that accordingly
     super.onBackPressed();  // this exits the app.
}
```

Documentation is available here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()

Comment: For ***"code .. to check what fragment you are on"*** - see `getActiveFragment()` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15543580/2162226

Answer (score 3):

use this (in kotlin)

```
activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
    // in here you can do logic when backPress is clicked
}
```

})

i think this is the most elegant way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Now the onBackPressed method is deprecated and we need to use this way (much simpler !):

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
          if(shouldInterceptBackPress()){
            // in here you can do logic when backPress is clicked
          }else{
            isEnabled = false
            activity?.onBackPressed()
          }
        }
    })
}
```

You can found full explanation [here](https://proandroiddev.com/backpress-handling-in-android-fragments-the-old-and-the-new-method-c41d775fb776)
With this example it shows how to do when you are not sure that you need to consume the back press event

Answer (score 0):

You can key press listener in android using `setOnKeyListener()`. And then, if you want to handle the back press, override the `onKey` method :

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         // do your thing
    }

}
```

Comment: The back button doesn't send a key event, it calls into onBackPressed instead.

Comment: @GabeSechan:  IMO, it works. I've tested this in Dialog Fragment, so it should work in fragment also.

Comment: It doesn't work.  It hasn't worked since 2010.  The back and home buttons are not capturable via onKeyPressed.  If you found a place where it does, its either a bug or a weird version of the OS from an OEM.

Comment: okay, I didn't know if it's 'supposed' to work or not. But I just tested in my dialog fragment. It indeed works. My device is : gennymotion emulator, running android 6.

Comment: I checked again, it works in `DialogFragment` but not in `Fragment`. Any explanation?