# OnBackPressed Activity to MainActivity Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, gradle, onbackpressed

I have Requirement to `OnBackPressed` From Activity to `MainActivity Fragment`. What I have Done to achieve this is Implement a Simple `super.onbackPressed`. This `super.onbackPressed` Bring Activity to Previous Activity.
I have Also done this, But My Requiremts does not matched to this, i.e OnBackpressed Activity to MainActivity Fragment..

```
   override fun onBackPressed() {
    val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.doyouwanttoclose))
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setTitle("Alert!!")
        .setNegativeButton("No",
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id -> dialog.cancel() })
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id -> this@MakeStylishActivity.finish() })
    val alert: AlertDialog = builder.create()
    alert.show()
}
```

I have Also Implemented these Solutions available on Stackoverflow but doesn't worked for me
[On Back Pressed in Android Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430970/on-back-pressed-in-android-fragments)

[Fragment pressing back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755550/fragment-pressing-back-button)

[How to detect when back button pressed in fragment android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859260/how-to-detect-when-back-button-pressed-in-fragment-android)..

I am Confused How this must Be Done, Or this is Not Possible..

Comment: please explain more i did not understand what you want to do go from X to y ?

Comment: @Arvin Rezaei The Scenario be Like, I have an Activity, That Activity contains a Fragment, From that Fragment It opens two activities, activity1 and 2,.. What i want is onBackPress Bring to Fragment on Main Activity From where It Started

Comment: cant you just start the main activity with     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); flag ? and then clearbackstack?

Comment: @ArvinRezaei How this would be donw

Comment: <activity 
   android:name=".YourActivity"
   android:launchMode="singleTask"/>

Comment: then start your main actiivty normaly

Comment: @ArvinRezaei Where I need to add this?

Comment: do it in your manifest , read about activity task
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJ3PKi-OrsAhWB26QKHXnHAfsQFjAAegQIDBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Fcomponents%2Factivities%2Ftasks-and-back-stack&usg=AOvVaw05TSZVp1PLj723QdVVzJML

Comment: It Does not work, It is opening slowly

Comment: @ArvinRezaei It is Giving Error, as It is not Run App