# Is there any way to detect if fragment is showing to user or not?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-lifecycle

Here are simple steps.

```
step1 : fragment1 was showing and it's already added to Backstack
step2 : fragment2 is added to Backstack and showing it now
step3 : fragment2 is removed from Backstack
```

So finally, `fragment1` is showing again to user.
In this situation, is there anyway to detect if fragment1 is showing again inner `fragment1`?

I tried with `OnResume()` but it doesn't work.

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1):

```
Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

if (currentFragment instanceof YourFragment) {

if(currentFragment.this.isVisible())
{
  //your code
}
}
```

Comment: Where does I need to add your code? Please read again my question. I want to detect it in fragment that is showing now.

Comment: @Passionate.C I believe he has answered your question. Your code goes in the second if statement. i.e current.this.isVisible()

Comment: I want to add the code to fragment1 to detect it. it's possible?

Comment: @Passionate.C Hope my answer can help.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the fragment in your transaction you should use a tag.

```
fragTrans.replace(android.R.id.content, myFragment, "MY_FRAGMENT");
```

...and later if you want to check if the fragment is visible:

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENT");
if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
   // add your code here
}
```

See also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

---

I just copied this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9295085/7232310
because I think is what you need. Otherwise you can check the following answers on the same question.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes. it helps but it needs to add code to Activity or something that manages the fragments. i want to detect in fragment1.

Answer (score 0):

Try `onAttach()`, this is to trigger if the fragment is showed.
`onDetach()` is to detect if the fragment is leaving the user interface.

For example: you have 3 fragment(frag1,frag2,frag3), every fragment you need to put the `onAttach()`

```
frag1 
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm frag 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 options

Try to override this behaviour and see if it works

```
void onHiddenChanged (boolean hidden)
```

As per documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged(boolean))

Or Other option is to `onStart()` / `onResume()` callback of lifecycle try to observe behaviour of fragments visibility state.

```
boolean isVisible ()
```

As per documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isVisible%28%29)

Comment: If you can drop code snippets will help us to play on that and fix issue.