# How to use instanceof operator for fragment with class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, instanceof

I need to check the current displayed fragment to avoid relaunch of same fragment class

To launch the fragment used code :

```
private Class mFragmentClass;

mFragmentClass = InfoFragment.class;

if (null != mFragmentClass) {
  try {
     mFragment = (Fragment) mFragmentClass.newInstance();
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_navigation_menu, mFragment).commit();
  } catch (InstantiationException exception) {
     exception.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalAccessException exception) {
     exception.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Need to check current displayed fragment:

```
if(mFragment instanceof (Fragment)mFragmentClass.newInstance())
```

is giving compile time error

> [),Expected,Type Expected]

Comment: The java instanceof operator is used to test whether the object is an instance of the specified type.It expects a class. 

Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/get-currently-displayed-fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for checking types that are only known at runtime:

```
mFragmentClass.isInstance(mFragment)
```

Comment: This is what am expecting.Thank u.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a static String in your Activity where you are opening the fragments

```
public static String currentFragment = "";
```

then in every fragments onResume you can give the name of the fragment to that string like this

```
MainActivity.currentFragment = "currentFrag";
```

Then you can check it whenever you want.

Comment: This is a genius approach! Thanks for this.