# How to check if we have been in this fragment before in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Let's say I have `fragment A` in my current view. I animate `myView` in `onCreateView` method. Then I commit another fragment `(fragment B`) on top of fragment stack. When I go back to `fragment A`, `myView` animation is again started which I don't want it to. I think I should move the animation part to some other method. Would you please help?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    animate myView;
    ...

    someOtherView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onClick(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .replace(R.id.framelayout_home,new Fragment_B()).commit();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Try animating the view only when `savedInstanceState == null`.

Answer (score 0):

When you get back from fragment B just get the instance of fragment A and do your need. 
Reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/9295085/9252060