# Getting activity's current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new in android app coding, and I am facing a question.

MainActivity has a navigationView, which links with different classes
A class I called "Station", so it will call like this

```
myFragment = new Station();
```

Station class extends Fragment, I used it to create fragments named

- Station_General_Fragment
- Station_ER_Fragment
- Station_WR_Fragment

MainActivity also has a MediaPlayer (I call it mp1), and I'm trying to do OnCompletionListener for mp1, each fragment does different things in OnCompletionListener

The trouble I am facing is
  Different OnCompletionListener in different classes mess up each other

What I am trying to do is

- Get what fragment the activity is viewing
- Compare with the fragment that OnCompletionListener located at
- If equals, then do the code inside OnCompletionListener of that fragment

Anyone can help me? I can explain more if anyone wanna help me but don't know what I am talking about. Thank You

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to illustrate the problem. To keep it minimal, I suggest that you start a new Android Studio project and add only the code you need to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get currently displayed fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/get-currently-displayed-fragment)