# Accessing fragments both method and content from main activiy (everything is null)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

Trying to implement changing an image within a class extending fragment. After clicking the button in the menu from `MainActivity` with *FragmentPagerAdapter* app always crashes.

At first, I got a null error from `getActivity()` within the fragment, then replaced these with sending `ImageView` from main activity button click. It helped for a moment then I had to move int array declaration from `onCreateView()` or else it was empty again, yet a final bad boy I had to face was `super(context)`.

According to Google and stuff that happens due to the creation of activity comes after `onCreateView()` hence `getActivity()` and context and public variables are unreachable. How to replace it? Where should I put some special line to get context from the fragment and get access to everything inside?

Here is my code

```
//from main activity click
private void loadImage() {
    ImageView v = findViewById(R.id.view_core);
    FragmentHistogram frag = new FragmentHistogram();
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions(); //that str also did not help
    frag.reseter(v);
}

//tried that in fragment but that did not help
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Activity){
        a=(Activity) context;
    }
}
```

===UPDATE===

```
// in MainActivity
TabAdapter adapter;
Fragment fr;
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tabs);

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    adapter = new TabAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager()); //FragmentPagerAdapter 
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    fr = adapter.getItem(1); 
} 

 // modified on click also in MainActivity
   private void loadImage() {
    ((FragmentHistogram) fr).reseter(v); //FragmentHistogram fragment class with reseter() method
}
```

But that also does not work, context is again null.
In `onCreate` I already have passed context `this` into `adapter` hence context is already not null, then I define exact fragment from its position and get method via casting. However, if even in that case I remove `v` from `reseter()` then the view cannot be found as it activity has not started.

One more thing I forgot to mention. I have an inner class within fragment class it required context. Maybe that is the problem?

```
class lHistogram extends View {

    public lHistogram(Context context, Bitmap bi) {            
        super(context);
    }
```

===UPDATE 2===

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
private Context mContext;

public TabAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new FragmentCore();
        default:
            return new FragmentHistogram();
    }
...
}
```

I guess that problem might be in fragment creation order. What I mean is having added to `onViewCreated` log lines I found out that no matter which order I set in `Fragment getItem(int position)` it always sends context to `FragmentCore`, which means even having `FragmentHistogram` showing as 1st page context is still on the second. What controls context assigning?

Comment: `FragmentHistogram frag = new FragmentHistogram();` will give you a new fragment not the current one .

Comment: @ADM well now that seems straightforwand, thank you! Any ideas how then can I access both method from class and class content altogether?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/get-currently-displayed-fragment

Comment: Did you add fragment into your activity? a random thought. maybe a complete code would helps

Comment: @hjchin I have updated the post, fragments are added inside of TabAdapter class, but I see now that problem determine what controls how and why context is assigned only to FragmentCore, and possibly after I could get context from it.

Comment: i see.. u should not get the fragment from adapter, it always return a new fragment. U should be able to get the fragment from SupportFragmentManager, like method https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#getFragments().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions, pick 1 or 2; both worked for my case:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51253168/8859693

Add to each `Fragment`'s `onCreate()`, try to call the method `setRetainInstance(true)`;

2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51271379/8859693

Add `mcontext=getContext();` class extention of `FragmentPagerAdapter`

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
private Context mContext;

public TabAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}
```