# Change toolbar title when fragment changes

Tags: android, set, toolbar

Hello developers out there,

I have an activity which contains several fragments. I want, that when the fragment changes, also the title of the toolbar changes. How probably many of you know

```
toolbar.setTitle("title")
```

does nothing while

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title")
```

works fine.

But I can't call `getSupportActionBar()` from my fragment, because it's no static method. Does anybody has an idea how could solve this?

Thanks too you
Greetings Pumpanickel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");
```

just make sure you don't call that before the `onActivityCreated()` so you don't get an exception

Comment: i dont get why this is working and without a cast to appcombatactivity it doesnt, but its fine for now, thanks a lot :)

Comment: these methods are inherited in the activity by the superclass AppCompatActivity. By adding the cast you know you'll be getting access to those methods even when you're inside the fragment

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
 getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title")
```

Comment: doenst work because i cant call a non static method from a static context

Answer (score 1):

Works for me in each onCreate of fragments use it this:

```
getActivity.setTitle("Your title");
```

Answer (score 0):

my answer is based on that .. u want to change the toolbar title in your activity from your fargment
so the toolbar is in your activity not in your fragment

well ,, u can use a toolbar in a fragment so u make the toolbar in a fragment 
or check which fragment is visible and change the toolbar title by its cases 
and this topic will help u
[get currently displayed fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/get-currently-displayed-fragment)