# Calling a fragment method from an Activity

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have a form in fragment A, after the user enters their information and presses on submit, they should get redirected to fragment B.

I can manage to call the fragment method, however I'm getting a NullPointerException error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

How I am calling the method in fragment B:

```
(new FragmentB()).infoSubmitted();
```

How could I effectively call the method in fragment B?

Comment: Your error indicated that _You are using context which is null_

Comment: Because `new FragmentB()` is not attached to Activity . So you need to get the reference of fragment which is currently attached .. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/how-do-i-get-the-currently-displayed-fragment)  if a Layout is a Container..

Answer (score 1):

You can do that way, but it isn't good approach.

Once you submit form in FragmentA, return results to Activity and then start FragmentB.

In FragmentA it would be like:

```
public void formSubmitted(){
     getActivity().startFragmentB(mFormData)
}
```

And in Activivity create a method:

```
public void startFragmentB(Form formData){
     // handle fromData
     // start fragmentB
}
```