# show/hide especific items from toolbar menu not working kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Iam creating a menu toolbar in `MainActivity`, that have body fragment (the only toolbar is set in the activity not within the fragments)

When the default fragment is set (HomeFragment), I want to hide `search` and `sort` icons from the toolbar menu, else to show them in  the other `ContentFragment`

`ContentFragment` can take different toolbar names `verbs, nouns, pronouns..` and `HomeFragment` only `Home`

this is why Im using `if(supportActionBar!!.title== "Home") {`

**MainActivity.kt**

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   transaction(HomeFragment)...commit()
    .....
  }

 //below bundle ends
  override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    if(supportActionBar!!.title== "Home") {
        menu?.findItem(R.id.db_menu_search)?.isVisible  = false
        menu?.findItem(R.id.db_menu_sort)?.isVisible   = false
    }else{
        menu?.findItem(R.id.db_menu_search)?.isVisible  = true
        menu?.findItem(R.id.db_menu_sort)?.isVisible   = true
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
}


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.header_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.db_menu_search -> {

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Search Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
            R.id.db_menu_sort -> {
                sortDialog()
            }

            R.id.header_menu_verbs -> {
                getToFragmentB("Verbs",1)
            }
          
        }
        return false
    }
```

header_menu.xml

```
 //just informative

 <item id=db_menu_search icon=ic_search />
 <item id=db_menu_sort icon=ic_sort />
 <item id=db_menu_verbs />
   <item id=db_menu_nouns /> ....
```

I added `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method expecting to make it work...it doesnt work properly

**what am doing wrong?**

How can I hide those two icons from the toolbar when HomeFragment is set in the activity and show them once the another fragment is displayed?

Comment: I think, that the problem is that you are detecting current fragment by it title. I don't know how do you set the title for each fragment, so it could be wrong title, when onPrepareOptionsMenu get called. To detect current fragment you should use fragmentManager: supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id) then you can use it in onPrepareOptionsMenu fragment != null && fragment.isVisible { show / hide icons depending on fragment }. How to find fragment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/how-do-i-get-the-currently-displayed-fragment

Comment: thank you. but I dont actually understand your point. so you tell me to check what fragment is being used at that especific moment, and use `onPrepare...` whitin the fragment code? or within the Main activity class. where should I supossed to use the code to make it work

Comment: I wrote, that I'm thinking, that in the moment of call onPrepareOptionsMenu you have the wrong title in toolbar, and toggle icons working wrong as the result. If you want, I can write working solution for you later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I describe main steps here, link to the working solution in the end

1. All items in menu.xml have parameter `android:visible="false"`
2. `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` should be in `onCreate()` of each fragment, where render icons in toolbar is necessary. Without it activity functions

   `onCreateOptionsMenu / onPrepareOptionsMenu` will never get called when fragment changes.

   ```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }
   ```
3. Handling showing/hiding icons in onPrepareOptionsMenu via supportFragmentManager. It's only the way to detect what fragment currently is displaying.

   ```
      override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    supportFragmentManager.fragments.forEach {
      when {
        it.tag == FragmentTag.Fragment1.tag && it.isVisible -> {
          menu?.findItem(R.id.action_fragment1)?.isVisible = true
          menu?.findItem(R.id.action_fragment2)?.isVisible = true
        }
        it.tag == FragmentTag.Fragment2.tag && it.isVisible -> menu?.findItem(R.id.action_fragment2)?.isVisible = true
        it.tag == FragmentTag.Fragment3.tag && it.isVisible -> menu?.findItem(R.id.action_fragment3)?.isVisible = true
      }
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
   ```

   }

Code to working solution: https://github.com/yellow-cap/android-handle-toolbar-icons

Comment: My friend, I tested that and works like a charm, not only solved this issue, I did lern something new as well!! +1

Comment: I have this other question..do you know how to solve it? thank you https://stackoverflow.com/q/66122287/13741397