# Is there any way to track what fragment/s are visible right now?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I work on a very large project. It has a lot of modules and views - activities and fragments. I need to understand what fragment and what activity are running at the moment. Then I need to move to this class of activity and fragment in the project. Is there any way to find the class name? maybe by logs or smth else?

Comment: Check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/how-do-i-get-the-currently-displayed-fragment?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler) for this. You will also get a lot of details from this tool. Just hover the mouse over the graph, it will show the fragment currently showing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Layout Inspector, a feature of android studio. When the app is running on a device that is connected to Android Studio, you can click on any item to see the view id, you can use these ids to find out which activity/fragment they belong to (through xml file)

[image: Layout inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Use UserVisibleHint for that:

boolean isVisible;

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        isVisible = isVisibleToUser;
    }
```

When you want to check the visibility of the fragment, simply check it.

```
if (isVisible) {
      //Fragment is visible
    } else {
      //Fragment is not visible
    }
```