# Finding the name of the current activity from live layout inspector

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I've got a physical device ready for debugging.
I want to track down the name of the curent activity using the Live Layout Inspector.
Seems like there's no such feature, but is there any roundabout way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, If you are using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 or newer, there is no such straight way with layout inspector like the former version. However, you can find the related layout xxx.xml name,which could also help.
[image]

Touch any view, find Declared Attributes at the right panel,then shows the layout name, with which will find activty easily.

And also check this: [Is there any way to track what fragment/s are visible right now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279784/is-there-any-way-to-track-what-fragment-s-are-visible-right-now/68281290#68281290)
Try the Profiler way.