# Android: Check if a fragment is visible

Tags: android

I have a FragmentActivity, some fragments and a service that is running in background. It is possible to check from the service if a specific fragment is visible?

Comment: It is not really a duplicated because the other question is asked in the context of a ViewPager, and the answers reflect that context. This is a more general question.

Comment: this is not a duplicate.

Comment: The solution that worked best for me was http://stackoverflow.com/a/6751537/1816603

Answer (score 54):

check `if(YourFragment.this.isVisible())`

Comment: How to in a Tabbed Action Bar? Navigation is messed up in this fragment scheme.

Comment: How navigation is messed up? What you want to achieve?

Comment: I have an Action Bar tabbed activity, Fragments consist of tabs, I have a button on the Action Bar which once pressed navigates to a different fragment say "Info about the app". As soon as user navigates to info, I disable it so that it does not get called redundantly, then I re-enable it once back is pressed but say if user navigates to info ( info gets disabled until back is pressed) but I want to enable it again if back is not pressed but navigation between tabs occurs.

Comment: So far I tried a number of things like referencing the Menu item in the on start and on resume of tab fragments but gives me a null pointer, I am now writing a detailed script and posting as a Question.

Comment: yeah, good, you must post question with attempted code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393016/enable-an-actionbar-button-each-time-navigation-within-tabs-occurs

Answer (score 21):

```
public boolean isFragmentUIActive() {
    return isAdded() && !isDetached() && !isRemoving();
}
```

Does the trick.

Comment: This returns false if i call it from the service, but maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Check the code below:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
            @Override
            public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
                super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
                if (visible) {
                    ...
                }
            }
```

It's from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager). Or you can also check [this one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged%28boolean%29).