# fragment.getView() return null after backpressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to change `textview` under attached `fragment` on activity so i stored `attachedFragment` as variable as code below

```
    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment); 
        attachedFragment = fragment;
    }
```

then when a button is clicked I call following code

```
        if(attachedFragment !=  null && attachedFragment.getView() != null)
        {
            TextView tvGender = (TextView) attachedFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_gender);
            if(tvGender!=null)
                tvGender.setText(R.string.title_step_one_gender);
        }
```

When I start the activity and it works fine until i changed into the next fragment and pressed back; the `attachedFragment.getView()` always returns null

**My question:**

1. How is it possible it returns null while the first time is okay?
2. What is the best solution to change textview/any other control
   within fragment? There are lots of fragments and I only need to
   change attached fragment.

nb: All code above are under main activity

Comment: i think in addition to checking attachedFragment !=  null, you should also make sure that the attachedFragment.isDetached() is false as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I misunderstood your question.  It sounds like your situation is, you attach fragment A, then you attach fragment B, then you press back, leaving you with fragment A.  In this case, attachedFragment is just a variable, so it continues to point to B, but since B is now detached, it is null.  Pressing back will not repopulate the variable attachedFragment with fragment A.

Try using findFragmentById or findFragmentByTag.  Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750069/get-the-current-fragment-object) for more info.