# Can't find Fragments in onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments

I admit I am still struggling with Fragments and currently I don't know where to load what:

At first I loaded my Fragment in OnCreate() of my Activity, but then I had difficulty to access it (via findViewById) and moved it to onStart(), but I can't still find the Views within the Fragments on onStart()...

So in onCreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout.myfrag);
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.iPortraitView);  // different for Landscape
if(fl.getChildCount() == 0)  {
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.iTestView, new AFragmentClass).commit();
}
else {
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.iTestView, new AFragmentClass).commit();
}
Log.d("myTest", String.valueOf(fl.getChildCount()));
```

Now the problem is that *fl.getChildCount()* always returns 0 in onCreate, thereby adding new Fragments, while actually there is something in there and when I call the same code (*fl.getchildCount()* ) in onCreate, I get the correct count (which obviously increases each time I change the orientation). And as a result I have overlapping Views from both my landscape and portrait layouts.

I'm a a loss here and guess I'm struggling with figuring out what to load when (and especially when I can access them). Furthermore, do I have to implement all Listeners for *potential* Views (like Buttons contained in the various Fragments) that I might load dynamically in my Fragments?

Comment: When you add your fragment in your activity, give it a String `TAG`, using the additional overload, 
`.add(R.id.iTestView, new AFragmentClass(), "AFragment").commit()`, that way later you can call `getFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("AFragment")` and you will be able to access the fragment. You can also use the fragment ID as in this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6751537/418505

Answer (score 0):

The `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` hasn't been called at that point in the Activity-Fragment life cycle.  `onCreate(Bundle bundle)` is called before `onCreateView()`, so there would be no views to get the count of at that point of execution.  See the lifecycle:  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html.

In order to set listeners, and other view modifications on your fragment, you need to overright the onCreateView() method within your fragment.