# Android ViewPager current page update happens in the next page

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and I'm using API version 4.4. I'm using a ViewPager to display a fragment exactly as described in this link. http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html.

What my app does is it let the user to take a picture from camera and when he clicks the next button he can add another image and he can go on keep doing that(also he can come to the previous page). I'm displaying his picture inside a imageView.

I update the imageView in the fragment in the `onActivityResult` method inside Fragment. The issue is, when I change imageView (To his camera picture) it happesn to the next page in the viewPager not in the current page. Also what I noticed is `onResume` function in my Fragment class fires multiple times when the page loads for the first time.

This is my code so far,

**MainActivity.java**

```
private static final int MAX_IMAGES = 10;
protected int currentIndex=0; // Which page we are currently in
private ImageFragment fragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pageAdapter = new TicketImageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    //LinearLayout uploadImage  = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.uploadImage));
    Button nextButton           = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextBttn);
    Button saveButton           = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    Button previousButton       = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previousBttn); 

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(fragment != null)
            {
                fragment.addTicketImage();
                displayTicketImages();
            }

            if(MAX_IMAGES > currentIndex)
            {
                currentIndex++;
                Log.d("Currect Index; ",currentIndex+"");
                setCurrentItem (currentIndex, true);
            }
        }
    });
// Set current page fragment so I can access it's methods
public void setFragment(TicketImageFragment fragment)
{
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //Don't worry about fragment been null, coz it is not. I Set the fragment in the on
    if(this.fragment != null)
    {
        this.fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

   public static class TicketImageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TicketImageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MAX_IMAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ImageFragment();
    }
}
```

}

**ImageFragment.java**

This is where I redirect the common user to the camera and display his picture like a preview in a imageView.

```
private TextView firstText;
private MainActivity activity;
View view;
ImageView imgPreview;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment,container,false);

    LinearLayout uploadImageBttn = ((LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.uploadImageButton));
    firstText                    = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.note));



    imgPreview = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ticketImage);

    uploadImageBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            activity.helper = new CameraHelper(v.getContext());
            activity.helper.captureImage(); // Capture image and save it
        }
    });

    this.activity  = (TicketImageActivity)getActivity();

    // Set fragment So the activity can call onActivityResult on this fragment
    this.activity.setFragment(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(imgPreview == null)
        Log.d("imagePreviewView", "NULL");
    else
        Log.d("UploadButton", "NOT NULL");

    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CameraHelper.getCode()) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            //ImageView imgPreview = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ticketImage);
            previewCapturedImage(imgPreview,"this is the image path");// Preview captured image

        } else if (resultCode == Activity. RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
 public void previewCapturedImage(ImageView imgPreview,String imagePath) {
    try {

        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // If the image view is hidden, show it
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImagePath,
                    options);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(mImagePath);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
            }
            else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
            }
            else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
            }
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true); // rotating bitmap
            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception :",e.getMessage());
        }
        //date = null;

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="400dp"/>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previousBttn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/Previous" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/saveButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextBttn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/Next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_fragment.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/uploadImageButton"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder">

         <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/uploadImageText"/>

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ticketImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/note"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/enterNote" />
```

Image capturing and saving it in the album works perfectly fine. The only issue is the image is displayed in the wrong page. When I Capture the image in the first page it displays the preview in the second page and when I capture it in the another page it shows in the next page.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `I'm using a pagerView`. Are you sure?

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, I corrected it to ViewPager. If anything else is wrong, please point that out to me since I'm new to this field. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
   this.activity.setFragment(this);
```

You should be doing this in onClick handler the adapter.

As ViewPager always instantiates the next page too MainActivity.fragment will not address the actual fragment. If you want to use fragment in onActivityResult then use setFragment when you call the intent.

That is easier said then done as the compiler will not accept that statement in onClick. I will think about it though how to do it correctly. Maybe you don't need to have this variable as there should be a possibility to determine the actual fragment in the Activity itself.

UPDATE: you can retrieve the right fragment in the Activity itself:

Use the answer of madx in [Get the current fragment object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750069/get-the-current-fragment-object)

It works for me.

Comment: I will definitely give this a shot. What do you mean by onClick handler greenapps? I want to set the image to the imageView once it returns to the activity after camera image captured. Thanks!

Comment: The onClick member function four lines before.

Comment: Ah great! I'll report the progress tomorrow. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all `ViewPager` instantiate next page when possible that is why you update may effect next page.
2. Make reference to current fragment on `MainActivity`.

   ```
   private Fragment currentFragment;
   ```
3. Update `currentFragment` reference with `Button` click.

   ```
   public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), OtherAcivity.class);
   ((MainActivity)getActivity).setCurrentFragment(MyFragment.this);
               startActivityForResult(intent);
           }
   ```
4. Use `currentFragment` refence from `MainActivity` when update fragment data.

   ```
   ((MainActivity)getActivity).getCurrentFragment().doSomething();
   ```